# Making an Asynchronous Web Request in an Init Function [Swift]

Tags: arrays, json, xcode, swift, asynchronous

I'm trying to return some JSON data from a class "RestApiManger" that handles HTTP/JSON requests and pass it into an array in my class "CardList", but I'm running into trouble.

Here is my CardList Class:

```
class CardList {

    var cards: [Card] = []
    var c = NSMutableArray()
    var items = NSMutableArray()

    static var sharedInstance = CardList()

    //MARK - Initalize
    private init(){

        //Dummy Data
        let helm = Card(name: "Helm of Testing", cost: 10, type: "Equipment", subType: "Head Armor", description: "Some say the Helmet of Testing helps keep it's wearers mind clear.")

        //Add to Array
        let c = [helm]

        //Get API Array
        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getElements { (json: JSON) in
            let results = json["results"]
            for (_, subJson) in results {
                let card:AnyObject = subJson["card"].object
                self.items.addObject(card)
            }
            print(self.items.count) // <---returns 1 (Web Data)
        }

        print(self.items.count)// <---returns 0 (Nothing)

        //Set to Returnable Array
        self.cards = c.sort { $0.cost < $1.cost }
    }

    //END Class
}
```

Seems like it's not passing to the items array on initialize until after it's called.  It's printing the array count inside the RestApiBlock, outside the block, it returns 0 (See the comments in the code with the arrows).  I'm a little unfamiliar with Swift and unsure why this happens.

Is there any way I can make this work?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do you get error ? What exactly happened with the code above ?

Comment: Eventually, I'm trying to move the data returned from the API array into an Array of class object "Card", however, I can only use the web data within the Rest Api Manager Block.  See the two `print(self.items.count)` lines?  The data isn't being stored in my "items" array for some reason.  It returns a count of 1 inside the block, returns a 0 outside the block.

Comment: So, arent you doing asynchronous request, that is what asynchronous call is supposed to do. You cannot get value immediately outside the block.

Comment: So how can I make this work?:  Store my Web data in a Class Array upon loading a UIView.  Is there even a way to make a Synchronous HTTP Request in Swift 2?  Or do I absolutely have to handle this stuff inside the UIViewController?

Comment: I described in your other question why your array is empty outside the asynchronous block. Asynchronous tasks is a elementary design to perform time consuming code in the background and keep the user interface responsive. Implement a completion handler to update the UI after receiving the data.

Answer (score 0):

This call to your API manager:

```
RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getElements
```

which takes a closure returns immediately, which means that execution of your code moves to this line:

```
print(self.items.count)
```

before the closure for completion of the request is called. This means that your items array is empty when you print its count that's why you're getting 0 there.

What you need to do is to do whatever you want with the items array inside that closure after the for loop.